# openssl with java and platform independence

Tags: java, openssl, platform-independent

If I use openssl with java will I lose the platform independence of the code? I want my code to work in both linux and windows.

Comment: Are you really need openssl? Java has a lot Security Providers for almost any cases. Look at Bouncy Castle as alternative.

Comment: Basically I want to retrieve the ciphersuite from a server.Java gives the ciphersuite but in TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA this form.I wanted a library that could help me in retrieving the ciphersuite in parsed form like Assymetric algo used-RSA,key length-128,Hashing -> sha.I think that it is possible with openssl.

Comment: Of course it possible do with OpenSSL, but even SunJSSE provider support it. And if you choose to use OpenSSL, you not exactly loose platform independency, but you should write slightly different code to both platform. Deploy process also may be difficult, then without OpenSSL. If you rewrite question, like, to say, "how can I do bla-bla-bla security bla-bla-bla encryption, bla-bla-bla, I do that with openSSL <example> but don't know how to do it with java, please help", someone, with pleasure, help you.